# Navigation bar shadow image to remove border line

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I added a shadow image to one of my navigation bars but when I segue from the view controller that has the shadow image

and I return the shadow image goes out of bounds.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "hey"), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "shadow")
}
```

This is how I set the shadow image for the initial view controller. I also have a container view in this view controller, could this be messing with the navigation bar?

Comment: I wish you could post more code. Exactly *which* overrides are you using? It matters.

Answer (score 3):

Set the second view controller's navigation's bar's `shadowImage` to just `UIImage()`. If it's *nil*, then the default shadow will appear.

Comment: also when I come back to the view controller that i segued from the shadow image overlaps my table view

Comment: Each view controller must set its desired properties on the navigation bar in `viewWillAppear()`; otherwise, the nav bar will look exactly like it did for the previous scene. All scenes pushed onto a given navigation controller share a single navigation bar instance.